# How to Bind/Replace Existing Data in HTML with Vue

Tags: html, vue.js

I already know how to make templates for Vue components, etc. in JavaScript.

However, let's say I have HTML generated on the server side (not with Vue, with a particular language called [UTL](https://help.bloxcms.com/knowledge-base/developers_corner/utl_template_language/article_f4479da4-65f3-11e5-89b3-73569e6ced8b.html))

```
<table>
     <tr>
          <td>[% example_var; %]</td>
          <td>[% another_var; %]</td>
     </tr>
</table>
```

And it would render on the front end like this:

```
<table>
     <tr>
          <td>Some Field</td>
          <td>Some Other Value</td>
     </tr>
</table>
```

Later, I may plan to bind/change the data in the HTML, and tie it to a Vue component. Like adding new rows, etc., but I would like to have the backend-generated values at least as a starting point or fallback in some cases.

How should I approach this? Ideally, I'd like to avoid writing 2 templates (server side and JS).

Comment: sounds like what you need is [Vue Guide: Slot](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-slots.html) + `v-html`

Comment: Possibly [hydration](https://ssr.vuejs.org/guide/hydration.html)

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to fill the initial data of your components from the script tag, using the data from your backend.

```
<script>
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    message: '[% example_var; %]' // <<< your template renderer engine tags
  }
})
</script>
```

However, in my understanding, the best practice to do what you want to do, would be using a store ([vuex](https://vuex.vuejs.org/)). Have the store load the initial values from your backend and your components rendering the data from this store.

Now, if you need those values printed within the html tags from the backend for SEO purposes, then you are looking for Server Side Rendering using Vue as a template rendering engine (mind that Vue uses the browser's DOM to come up with an html output). In this case, you will need to intercept all http requests to your server, run a virtual browser's DOM server side to make it render your components with the desired data, grab the HTML output of the DOM and pass it as the response of the request.

If you want to save some gray hairs, I would suggest you having a look at [Nuxt.js](https://nuxtjs.org/) since these guys did an amazing job creating a SSR engine for Vue.